# DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND Failed to find the data source: com.crealytics.spark.excel

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, spark-excel

I'm trying to submit a java spark program with the package `crealytics.spark-excel`.

The java file looks like this:

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import com.crealytics.spark.excel.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Spark_Excel")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();
        String filePath = "/home/arman/Desktop/resources/example_XLSX_5000.xlsx";
        Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
                .option("header", "true")
                .load(filePath);
        dataset.show();

        dataset.write()
                .format("excel") // Or .format("excel") for V2 implementation
                .option("header", "true")
                .partitionBy("Country")
                .save("/home/arman/Desktop/output/partitioned");

        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

The pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-excel</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <name>spark-excel</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Spark Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Spark SQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spark Excel Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.crealytics</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-excel_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1_0.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

It's working correctly, if I run the java class from intellij idea
but using `spark-submit --class org.example.Main spark-excel-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` I become the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: com.crealytics.spark.excel. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.
```

I have tried with both formats "com.crealytics.spark.excel" and "excel"
and tried with different versions of the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

`spark-excel_2.12` is not included in the driver classpath.

You can either:

- Include the spark excel dependency in your application JAR.
- Pass the dependency at runtime. Either pass `--packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:3.4.1_0.19.0` in your spark-submit command, or by passing the configuration `spark.jars.packages` set to the maven coordinates of the dependency.

Comment: Thanx. It's works